# Unexpected behavior with "set -o errexit" on AIX

Tags: linux, aix, subshell

This script shell works fine on GNU/Linux but not on AIX 5.3

```
#!/bin/sh

echo $SHELL

set -o nounset -o errexit

[ 1 -eq 1 ] && {
  echo "zzz"
} && echo "aaa" && [ 1 -eq 0 ] && echo "bbb"
echo "ccc"
```

On GNU/Linux, I've got the expected output :

```
/bin/bash
zzz
aaa
ccc
```

On AIX, I've got this one :

```
/bin/ksh
zzz
aaa
```

Without "set -o nounset -o errexit" it works fine... I don't understant why. Could you explain me what is wrong in my script shell.

Thanks,

Rémy

---

Edit 18 nov. : Precision

> set -e
>   When this option is on, if a simple command fails for any of the
>   reasons listed in Consequences of Shell Errors or returns an exit
>   status value >0, and is not part of the compound list following a
>   while, until, or if keyword, and is not a part of an AND  or  OR 
>   list,  and  is  not  a  pipeline    preceded by the ! reserved word,
>   then the shell shall immediately exit.
>   http://explainshell.com/explain?cmd=set+-e

In my example, the second test "[ 1 -eq 0 ]" is part of an AND, so I should see the output "ccc". This test returns 1, it traps the output "bbb", but should'nt exit the script.

Rémy

Comment: I guess `/bin/sh` in your Linux (probably `ash` or `dash`) simply doesn't understand `set -o errexit`. Use bash (let the first line be `#!/bin/bash`) Edit: env `SHELL` being `/bin/bash` doesn't prove anything, don't rely on it.

Answer (score 0):

Have the same behavior on AIX 6 and 7

Rémy